# mysql - Too Many database connections on Amazon RDS

Tags: database, performance, rds

[db connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaxB0.jpg)
What is the reason to this issue?
I see 3-4 connections steadily but in every 6 hours i see more than 100 database connections which is making my rds slow. Please let me know what may be the reasons behind this and what can be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to tell the reason for this without looking through your code.

But there are a few things to look at when you investigate the issue:

- Make sure that you use some sort of caching mechanism in front of your DB (Redis, Memcache etc.)
- Verify that you only make DB write operations when it is absolutely necessary, unneeded write operations can have a dramatic impact on your DB performance.

Comment: Could you please tell me, in which operation it opens a new mysql connection?

Comment: New connections are needed before you make any request (read/write) to the DB. Usually, it is part of the initialization code for your server-side script.